# no priority for z-index in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have assigned `z-index` to all the tags according to their priority. The tags with "b1" and "b2" ids need to have `absolute` position because I need to move their position with javascript.

However, I need the tag with "top" id to sit on "b1" and its children. Although it has a higher z-index, it still lies beneath.

This is the example:

```
HTML:
<div id="container">
     <div id="b1">
          <div id="HF">
               The main text >
          </div>
          <div id="nv_1">
               <a href="#">aaaaa</a>
               <a href="#"> bbbbbb </a>
               <a href="#">cccccc</a>
               <a href="#">dddddd </a>
          </div>
     </div>
     <div id="top"></div>
     <div id="b2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    width:1280px;
    height:762px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;}

#b1{
    height:78px;
    width:270px;
    top:0px;
    text-align:center;
    border: solid 2px #D24726;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;}

#b2{
    width:270px;
    height:80px;
    text-align:center;
    top: 82px;
    border: solid 2px #14826D;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;}

#top{
    position:absolut;
    width:160px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:yellow;
    z-index:3;}
```

Comment: You are caught by *stacking context* see here: https://liebdich.biz/zindexmania

Comment: @DOCASAREL — #top and #b1 are siblings, so there isn't a stacking context problem here.

Comment: @Quentin Whoops, did not read the html

Comment: @DOCASAREL — That was my original assumption too. It's not well formatted HTML.

Comment: @Quentin But there are more to ignite a stacking context, see link %)p

Answer (score 6):

You misspelt `absolute` (the `e` is missing from the end). The invalid property is ignored. The `position` property remains set to `static` and the `z-index` property doesn't apply (because it only applies to positioned elements).

This would have been picked up had you used [a validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Comment: Thanks for the validator link - That's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelt absolute so the div has no position and as you probably know, z-index does not work without a position.